# Trying to detect scroll direction in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

I want to move some html elements in the direction of the scroll direction. I've added a scroll event listener which updates the state of the scroll position. I also have a useRef that stores the previous value of the scroll position every time it changes. I compare the previous value and the current scroll position. If the scroll position is greater, then that means the scroll direction is down. Otherwise, the scroll direction is up. However, this code doesn't work. The condition always seems to read false. How can I detect the scroll direction using react.

```
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition]=useState(window.scrollY);
  const prevScrollPosition=useRef(0);

  useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('scroll',((e)=>{
      setScrollPosition(window.scrollY);
    }))
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    prevScrollPosition.current=scrollPosition;

    
    
    if(scrollPosition>prevScrollPosition.current){
      document.querySelector(".scalp").style.top=(document.querySelector(".scalp").offsetTop+7)+"px";
      document.querySelector(".brain").style.top=(document.querySelector(".brain").offsetTop+3)+"px";

    }else{
      document.querySelector(".scalp").style.top=(document.querySelector(".scalp").offsetTop-7)+"px";
      document.querySelector(".brain").style.top=(document.querySelector(".brain").offsetTop-3)+"px";
    }

  },[scrollPosition])

  
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <video className="cloudsVideo" autoplay playsinline autoplay loop muted src="Pexels Videos 3723.mp4" muted loop autoplay alt="clouds"></video>
      <video className="spaceVideo" autoplay playsinline autoplay loop muted src="pexels-ahnaf-piash-5747525.mp4" muted loop autoplay alt="space"></video>
      <img className="scalp" src="scalp.png"/>
      <img className="brain" src="Brain-PNG-Photos.png"/>
      <img className="head" src="head.png"/>

      <h1>{scrollPosition}</h1>
      <h1>{prevScrollPosition.current}</h1>
      <h1>{scrollPosition-prevScrollPosition.current}</h1>
      

      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You're setting `prevScrollPosition.current = scrollPosition' immediately before checking if scrollPosition is greater than prevScrollPosition. Moving the prevScrollPosition update to the end of the useEffect should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work for you:

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export const useScrollDirection = () => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState<number>(0);
  const [isScrollingUp, setIsScrollingUp] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isScrollingDown, setIsScrollingDown] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const prevScrollPosition = useRef<number>(0);

  const handleScroll = useCallback(() => {
    prevScrollPosition.current = scrollPosition;
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    setScrollPosition(position);
  }, [scrollPosition]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true });

    if (scrollPosition - prevScrollPosition.current > 0) {
      setIsScrollingUp(false);
      setIsScrollingDown(true);
    } else if (scrollPosition - prevScrollPosition.current < 0) {
      setIsScrollingDown(false);
      setIsScrollingUp(true);
    }
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, [handleScroll, scrollPosition]);

  return { isScrollingDown, isScrollingUp };
};
```